# Не работает программа строк

Tags: c#

"Считывает текст из файла и выводит на экран только предложения, состоящие из заданного количества слов".

Не работает программа строк. Вернее работает, но не до конца. Считывает тупо строчку, но не видит знаки препинания. Если задать 4 слова, то программа верно напишет строчку `aa s gg gg`., а если задать 3, программа ничего не выдает, а должна `aa s d, a bb ccc`!

Например, есть текст из файла:

aaa bbb cc. aa s d.
a
bb
ccc!
aa s gg gg.

Мой код:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;
namespace FilesAndStrings
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Write("Введи количество слов предложения: ");
            double slova = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("text.txt");
            string predlojenie;
            while ((predlojenie = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                if (predlojenie.Split(' ').Count() == slova)
                    Console.WriteLine(predlojenie);
            }
            sr.Close();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Как можно правильно дописать код?

Comment: Я попытался исправить форматрование, но не уверен, что правильно. Используйте символ backtick для выделения предложений в тексте. Используйте два пробела в конце предолжений, для создания переноса строки. Исправьте таким образом свои входные данные, чтобы стало понятно, что куда.

Comment: `double slova = Convert.ToDouble` заменить на `int slova = Convert.ToInt32`, а дальше уже от входных данных зависит. Смотрите внимательно, может в файле есть лишние пробелы.

Comment: Да, пробелы есть a bb и bb ccc. Но их нельзя убирать по заданию